# Oracle : Want to convert Substring to a useable, sortable date

Tags: oracle, date

1st Post go easy on me.

I'm using this Substring to pull part of a Field, this date I assume is probably non Standard (ddmmmyy) - how can I enhance this command so that I can use this a sortable Date Field, I'm guessing Cast but have no idea of Syntax etc ??

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Host_Name,-9) as Decom_Date
```

Output

```
DECOM_DATE
31Oct2018
31May2018
31May2018
31Mar2017
31Jul2018
```

TIA

Comment: Hi interesting, you can use `to_date` with the format, perhaps `to_date(the_string, 'ddyyymm')

Comment: Use `to_date(SUBSTR(Host_Name,-9) , 'DDMonYYYY') as decom_date`

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [the TO_DATE function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) is designed for:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Host_Name,-9), 'DDMonYYYY') as Decom_Date
```

It doesn't affect you here but bear in mind that oracle dates can only store down to a second precision. Also, if you have any rogue data in the table that can't be cant be parsed as a date you'll get  "not a valid..." or "a nonnumeric was found where a numeric was expected".

Be mindful that your strings here are in English but parsing MON (3 letter month name) can be regionally contextual so this code might not work on a server with a different NLS; for example consider passing 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' as the third argument to TO_DATE if you know your strings will always be English month names

Comment: LOL! If you know strings will always be **English** month names, then I'd set `nls_date_language = english` :)

Comment: Indeed -  some may find it amusing (or an affront) that oracle has a language of "American" but believe it or not, it's right there in the fine manual I'd linked to! :)